# Basis for a box topology and product topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I am studying the "Product Spaces" from Munkres's "Topology" on my own.

Let me tell about box topology and product topology.

Let $\{X_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in J}$ be an indexed family of topological spaces. Take basis for a topology on  $$\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_{\alpha}$$ the collection of all sets of the form $$\prod_{\alpha \in J} U_{\alpha}$$ where each $U_{\alpha }$ is open in $X_{\alpha}$ for each $\alpha \in J$. The topology generated by the basis is called the box topology.

Now the product topology on $\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha$ is defined as the topology generated by the subbase which consists the elements of the form $\pi_{\beta} ^{-1} (U_\beta)$ where $U_\beta$ is open in $X_\beta$ and $\pi _{\beta}$ be the projection map. This definition proves that the basis of the product topology on  $\prod_{\alpha  \in J} X_{\alpha}$ is the collections of sets of the form $$\prod_{\alpha  \in J} U_{\alpha}$$ where $U_\alpha$ is open in $X_\alpha$ and $U_\alpha = X_\alpha$ for all but finitely many values for $\alpha$.

Now I was trying to answer the following question:

$\textbf{Question:}$ Suppose the topology on each space $X_{\alpha}$ is given by a basis $\mathcal{B_{\alpha}}$. The collection of all sets of the form $$\prod _{\alpha \in J} B_{\alpha}$$ where $B_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{B_{\alpha}}$ for each $\alpha \in J$ will serve as a basis for the box topology on $\prod _{\alpha \in j} X_{\alpha}$. Also the collection of the all sets of the same form, where $B_\alpha \in  \mathcal{B_{\alpha}}$ for finitely many indices $\alpha$ and  $B_{\alpha} = X_{\alpha}$ for all the remaining indices, will serve as a basis for the product topology $\prod_{\alpha \in J} X_{\alpha}$.

$\textbf{My Attempts:}$

Given that each space $X_\alpha$ is given by a basis $\mathcal{B_\alpha}$. Thus each $B_\alpha \in \mathcal{B_\alpha}$ is open in $X_\alpha$. Thus the product of any basis elements, i.e. $\prod_{\alpha \in J} B_{\alpha}$ is open in box topology and product topology. Therefore, the topology specified in the problem is coarser than the box topology  and product topology.

Now we will prove that the topology defined in the theorem is finer than both box topology and product topology. To prove this, let  $U = \prod_{\alpha \in J} U_{\alpha}$. Now $U$ is a basis for box topology if each $U_\alpha$ is open in $X_\alpha$ and it will also be a basis element of product topology if $U_\alpha = X_\alpha$ for all but finitely many values of $\alpha$. Now since $U_\alpha$ is open in $X_\alpha$, then for each $x_\alpha \in U_\alpha$ there is a basis element $B_\alpha$ of $\mathcal{B_{\alpha}}$  such that $x_{\alpha} \in B_{\alpha} \subseteq U_\alpha$. Thus, $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in J} \in \prod_{\alpha \in J} B_{\alpha} \subseteq \prod_{\alpha \in J} U_{\alpha}$. Therefore, $$\prod_{\alpha \in J} U_{\alpha} = \bigcup \limits_{\prod_{\alpha \in J} B_{\alpha} \subseteq \prod_{\alpha \in J} U_{\alpha}} B_\alpha$$ where $B_\alpha$ is a basis element if $U_\alpha$ is a proper subset of  $X_{\alpha}$ and $B_{\alpha} = X_\alpha$  if $U_\alpha = X_\alpha$. Thus the topology  in the problem is finer than the both box topology and product topology.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: As an example to guide intuition: let $J=\Bbb N$ and $X_\alpha=\Bbb R$ for each $\alpha\in J$, so that we are considering the space $\Bbb R^\infty$. Let $A = (0,1)^\infty \subset \Bbb R^\infty$. Is $A$ open in the box topology? Is $A$ open in the product topology?

Comment: You should search this site. I am certain the differences between the box topology and the product topology have been covered a lot.